# Firebase rate limits per second, per user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When using firebase firestore, the [documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) say that `...you can update a single document only once per second`. Is this per frontend client(my web application)? I can run multiple clients at the same time and the updates will happen multiple times per second so i'm confused at the rate limits.

What happens once that limit does exceed the once per second? Do the firebase function throw an error back to the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit applies to any and all clients writing to a single document.  If the limit is exceeded, it will generate an error in the client code.  The limit is not really a hard limit.

Read more:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/495
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sXmPclfystk

Comment: Is there a general number as far as what the `sustain` time period may be? Or is that too much of a variable to predict? For example if i kept writing to the db for MORE than 1QPS for 5 minutes, it would throw errors?

Comment: I don't think there are any guarantees or estimates on that.  Just plan for what's stated in the docs.